# How does compiler differentiate between float and doubl arguments in overloaded

Tags: c++

Suppose there are 2 functions

```
void hello(float x)
{ cout<<x*x;}

void hello (double x)
{cout<<x*x;}
```

And if the function call is: hello(5.0);
Which function will be called?

Comment: What do you think `x²` means in C++? To me it means your code will not compile.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm sorry, I meant x*x :)

Comment: It probably depends on your compiler's choice of default float type for constant, you can also use 5.0f 5.0L to specify the type of your constant.

Comment: @HaochenWu The compiler has no choice, 5.0 is a `double`

Comment: @john You are right, I forget that polymorphism is a c++ thing. Was thinking some legacy c compilers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How a floating point literal is treated either double or float in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757815/how-a-floating-point-literal-is-treated-either-double-or-float-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 3):

Double.

Float litterals end with a `f` suffix, as in `5.0f`. `5.0` is a double.

Answer (score 2):

There's no ambiguity here. The ISO C++ standard specifies that floating point literals, if not suffixed with `f`/`F` or `l`/`L`, in which cases it will be treated as `float` or `long double`, respectively, **is of type `double`**.

The compiler is mandated to compile `hello(5.0)` into a call of `hello(double)` in your case.

Quoting n4296, Section 2.13.4/1:

> **The type of a floating literal is `double` unless explicitly specified by a suffix**. The suffixes `f` and `F` specify
>   `float`, the suffixes `l` and `L` specify `long double`. If the scaled value is not in the range of representable
>   values for its type, the program is ill-formed.